# How do I bring my current branch up to date while maintaining added work?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

So the scenario is as such:

I needed to do work for a feature I'm implementing called "split". I created a branch called split and did all of my work on it.

In the meantime, there was a breaking change that needed implementation in production, so I switched back to master, committed my changes, and deployed them.

Now I'm back to working on the 'split' branch. I checked it back out this morning, but now I need to bring it up to speed with the master branch which contains the breaking changes that I implemented.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase master` and then resolve the conflicts and you are done. But this should only be done on non-pushed local branches that no other users have work based on. If potentially others have branches based on your branch, you should better merge the lastest master changes into your feature branch, but with rebase you get nicer linear history instead of ladder history.

Answer (score 0):

You can `pull master` branch to get the breaking changes.

```
$ git checkout split                  # go to split branch 
$ git pull origin master              # pull, take the master's changes
```

Or, you can `rebase`. Take all the changes of masters and put your commit on `top in git log`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git pull --rebase origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `merge` or `rebase` the master branch to your feature branch.

First of all, you have to `commit` or `stash` all the changes that are there on the feature branch, so that the working directory is clean. Then, do `git rebase master` to rebase or `git merge master` to merge. It's also good to understand the difference: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/.